# Why does HTTP/1.1 recommend to be conservative with opening connections?

Tags: http, tcp, connection

With HTTP/1.0, there used to be a recommended limit of 2 connections per domain. More recent HTTP RFCs have relaxed this limitation but still warn to be conservative when opening multiple connections:

> According to RFC 7230, section 6.4, "a client ought to limit the number of simultaneous open connections that it maintains to a given server".

More specifically, besides HTTP/2, these days, browsers impose a per-domain limit of 6-8 connections when using HTTP/1.1. From what I'm reading, these guidelines are intended to improve HTTP response times and avoid congestion.

Can someone help me understand what would happen with congestion and response times if many connections were opened by domain? It doesn't sound like an HTTP server problem since the amount of connection they can handle seems like an implementation detail. The explanation above seems to say it's about TCP performance? I can't find any more precise explanations for why HTTP clients limit the number of connections per domains.

Comment: There could be hundreds of reasons. I'll start with only one: suppose the server is a small one, serving a site with hundreds of files (which is not uncommon) and the client is on an extremely slow connection and opens one connection per file as allowed by HTTP/2 taking all available sockets on the server. On certain edge cases, a single client could singlehandedly cause a brief DoS it it takes too long to release the sockets (because it's on a slow connection). Maybe not one client but 100 slow clients at the same time... If the site is a high traffic one, well you get the picture

Comment: @JavierLarroulet I definitely see the problems that a high amount of connections can bring to a server, but it seems you could have the same issues with just a high number of clients vs a high number of connections per client. It also largely depends on the implementation of your server.

The way I'm reading the spec there seems to be something specific about *one* client opening many connections to *one* domain?

Maybe I'm just overthinking this?

Comment: Yes you are in fact correct. A very high number of clients who adhere to self-restricting the amount of open connections would cause the same issue, and that's where load balancing and scaling come in. the thing is however that not limiting the amount of connections would be very detrimental to small sites. Keep in mind that HTTP/2 allows content-serving to be parallelized instead of waterfalled so in theory a client would be able to max out the server's max connections in an attempt to "monopolize" (is that a word?) server resources to get content before other clients.

Comment: I'm sure there's quite a lot of other reasons, but that's the most tangible one I can think of

Answer (score 0):

The primary reasoning for this is resources on the server side.

Imagine that you have a server running Apache with the default of 256 worker threads.  Imagine that this server is hosting an index page that has 20 images on it.  Now imagine that 20 clients simultaneously connect and download the index page; each of these clients closes these connections after obtaining the page.

Since each of them will now establish connections to download the image, you likely see that the connections increase exponentially (or multiplicatively, I suppose).  Consider what happens if every client is configured to establish up to ten simultaneous connections in parallel to optimize the display of the page with images.  This takes us very quickly to 400 simultaneous connections.  This is nearly double the number of worker processes that Apache has available (again, by default, with a pre-fork).

For the server, resources must be balanced to be able to serve the most likely load, but the clients help with this tremendously by throttling connections.  If every client felt free to establish 100+ connections to a server in parallel, we would very quickly DoS lots of hosts. :)